# R return unique values per row in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I have a structure which I want to apply a conditional on and have it return only 1 value per row.

```
> blah
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    5
[2,]    6    9
[3,]    9    4
[4,]    5    1
[5,]    7    1
```

Suppose, my conditional is `blah == 5`.

```
> blah.tf
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE
```

I want a function that will return only the first TRUE value per row, and NA otherwise.

So my returned result would be c(5,NA,NA,5,NA). I can't figure out how to apply this simple row based filter.

```
blah <- structure(c(5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L,2L))

blah.tf <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))
```

Editing for clarity -

The question was poorly phrased. The conditional is variable and not static.

Suppose the conditional is `blah.tf <- (blah >= 4 & blah <= 6)`. This would return in a T/F column of

```
> blah.tf
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE
```

I want to return a vector of the first value of `blah` that meets the conditional by row. In the case of the new conditional, the values would be `c(5,6,4,5,NA)`.

Answer (score 3):

We can compare 'blah' with 5 to create a logical matrix, get the `rowSums`, convert to logical vector (`!=0` and use `ifelse` to convert the TRUE to 5 and others to NA.

```
ifelse(rowSums(blah==5)!=0, 5, NA)
```

Or as @DavidArenburg suggested, we don't need an `ifelse`

```
(NA^!rowSums(blah == 5))*5
```

#### Update

Using the updated condition, we can use `max.col` to get the column index of the first TRUE element in each row (if the row has only FALSE, we can create NA using `NA^!rowSums(ind)`), `cbind` with the row index and extract the elements from 'blah'.

```
ind <- (blah >=4) & (blah <= 6)
blah[cbind(1:nrow(ind), max.col(ind, 'first')* NA^!rowSums(ind))]
#[1]  5  6  4  5 NA
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the value which isn't static, so just setting it to 5 won't work. I need to use the T/F matrix to look up the value, but I want to return only 1 value per row. So, if the conditional were blah==9, I would want to return c(NA,9,9,NA,NA).

Comment: @Shuo In that case your question is unclear and probably going to be put on hold unless you will explain exactly what you need, show different use cases, and explain why this solution won't work for them.

Comment: @Shuo If the conditional value is 5 or 9, create an object i.e. `v1 <- 5; ifelse(rowSums(blah==v1)!=0, v1, NA)`

Comment: @shuo what's the problem with akrun solution?

Comment: Btw, you could code golf it using `(NA^!rowSums(blah == 5))*5`

Comment: @DavidArenburg That would have been my first option, but it is difficult to compete with `ifelse` solution, so I posted that first

Comment: Updated the post to clarify the issue with ifelse

Comment: `blah.tf <- blah >= 4 & blah <= 6` - my mistake